# Allow 'auto' value for width/height attributes of image tags in HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Currently my htmlpurifier doesn't allow 'auto' value for the height and width attributes on image tags , but only numeric values .

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)%'); //allow YouTube and Vimeo
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

How i can proceed for allow the auto value ?

Answer (score 2):

While the CSS attributes `width` and `height` support the `auto` value, the HTML attributes `width` and `height` do **not** support `auto`. See ["Objects, Images, and Applets in HTML documents" > "Width and height"](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html#h-13.7.1) together with the definition of ["Length"](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/types.html#type-length).

One of HTML Purifier's features is that it forces the HTML you supply to conform to the standards. In a nutshell, this increases security by reducing the ability to exploit undefined behaviour in browsers.

However, in this case, HTML Purifier is actually *even stricter* by default and disallows percentages. This is independent of the `auto` question - but it's worth noting you would have to set [`HTML.MaxImgLength`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.MaxImgLength) to `null` to even enable percentages. This is a sign that you should think about whether you really want this.

The behaviour you want (`auto`) may be best emulated by simple *not supplying* a `width` and `height` attribute.

That said, you can still tell HTML Purifier to treat this case differently:

### Patching

*(i.e. changing the behaviour **by** changing the HTML Purifier source code.)*

In this case, patching the code isn't hugely easier than overriding the code, so I don't recommend it, but understanding how to patch HTML Purifier can help you understand why overriding it works:

If you want to patch HTML Purifier to allow `width` and `height` to support the `auto` value, you should patch **library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLModule/Image.php**. The current restriction is in these lines:

```
                // According to the spec, it's Length, but percents can
                // be abused, so we allow only Pixels.
                'height' => 'Pixels#' . $max,
                'width' => 'Pixels#' . $max,
```

You'll want to add a class to **library/HTMLPurifier/AttrDef/HTML/** so you can address it easily in the definition. For example, `Pixels` refers to the class `HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_HTML_Pixels` in **library/HTMLPurifier/AttrDef/HTML/Pixels.php**. I'd recommend using either `Pixels` or `Length` as a template for the class that will support the value `auto`.

### Overriding

*(i.e. changing the behaviour **without** changing the HTML Purifier source code.)*

If you want to override the HTML Purifier behaviour, check out the [Customize!](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) documentation on the HTML Purifier site.

Superficially, overriding the behaviour will look a lot like the patching process:

You should still write a class that looks a lot like **library/HTMLPurifier/AttrDef/HTML/Pixels.php** or **library/HTMLPurifier/AttrDef/HTML/Length.php**, but put it somewhere outside of the HTMLPurifier code base.

Once you have that class, you can use the following configuration code to override the default `width` and `height` behaviour:

```
$htmlDef = $this->configuration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$htmlDef->addAttribute('img', 'width', new YourOwnClass());
$htmlDef->addAttribute('img', 'height', new YourOwnClass());
```

There may be some roadblocks on the way to getting this to work (it's been a few years since I tinkered with HTML Purifier on this level!), but this should set you on a good path to getting your hands dirty on HTML Purifier code. :)