# HTML Purifier not allowing % height and % width in img tag style attribute

Tags: php

I have searched a lot for an answer on this but the following setting is not allowin height or width in the style attribute to use percentages:

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'img[src|alt|height|width|style],span[style],strong');
```

Note the same behaviour occurs in the height and width attributes. Values with "px" are left intact.

There are no errors produced in the logs.

I'm happy to use an alternative solution.

The source has this:

```
          // According to the spec, it's Length, but percents can
            // be abused, so we allow only Pixels.
            'height' => 'Pixels#' . $max,
            'width' => 'Pixels#' . $max,
```

Is % really a problem, can I alter the source somehow if not?

Comment: Do you have magic-quotes enabled in php? (eg: `<?php echo "hello $name"; ?>`). The [docs](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs) mention that may cause attributes to go missing.

Comment: Sorry I had to edit the question, it turns out the removal is happening in the style attribute as well.

Comment: The "Overriding" process, as described here, any help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46652438/1427878

Comment: Thanks, that is somewhat useful but I find it amazing that I would have alter the source code to allow percentages in CSS styles. Is there a good alternative to HTML Purifier?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was HTML Purifier does not allow percent at all for CSS units, I have altered the source to allow this unit. I can't imagine this is a security risk as it is a valid unit type that is widely used, I am amazed this is not handled by seemingly the only proper HTML sanitiser for PHP.

Firstly in the HTMLPurifier_Length class the % symbol is added to the allowedUnits array:

```
protected static $allowedUnits = array(
    'em' => true, 'ex' => true, 'px' => true, 'in' => true,
    'cm' => true, 'mm' => true, 'pt' => true, 'pc' => true,'%' => true,
    'ch' => true, 'rem' => true, 'vw' => true, 'vh' => true,
    'vmin' => true, 'vmax' => true
);
```

The next thing to do was to add some code to the HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_CSS_Length class:

```
// Handle percentages

if (substr($string, strlen($string) - 1) == '%') {
    
    $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 1);
        
    if (!is_numeric($string)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    $int = (int)$string;

    if ($int < 0) {
        return "100%";
    }

    if ( $int > 100 ) {
        return "100%";
    }
   
    return $length->toString();

}
```

This must come after:

```
$length = HTMLPurifier_Length::make($string);

if (!$length->isValid()) {
    return false;
}
```

As this does the unit symbol check, and the new code must be pasted before the checks for min/max from the config.

It was not possible to use the min/max checks as these are based on a pixel values set in the config.